# Problem with ggplot geom-tile convert to plotly chartusing ggplotly

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, ggplotly, geom-tile

I tried to convert the ggplot geom-tile chart to plotly by using ggplotly function. However, I realized that the outcomes are different. Please refer for the link below to view the difference. Besides that, ggplotly chart also missing colorbar. Please help.

Image:
[Difference between ggplot and ggplotly chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4T6rb.png)

This is the code that I referred to : https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/285-waffer-map.html

Code:

```
madeUp=read.table("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/R-graph-gallery/master/DATA/madeUp.csv", sep=",", header=T)


library(tidyverse)


theData <- madeUp %>% 
  group_by(X.Axis, Y.Axis, Group) %>% 
  dplyr::summarize(statistic=mean(randVals, na.rm = TRUE))

fig <- ggplot(theData, aes(X.Axis, Y.Axis)) +

  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0,20), ylim = c(0,20)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,20)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,20))+

  geom_tile(aes(fill=statistic))+
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title='Legend'))+

  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill= 'white', color = 'white'),
    panel.grid.major = element_line(color='#E0E0E0'),
    panel.grid.minor = element_line(color='#E0E0E0')
  )+

  ggtitle('Wafer Map')+
  facet_wrap(~Group)+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = rainbow(100))

#Convert to ggplotly chart
fig <- ggplotly(fig)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you stumbled over a bug (or two) in `ggplotly` (maybe you should raise an issue on [github](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly)).

1. The first issue is that the "gaps" in the dataset get lost when converting the ggplot via `ggplotly`.
2. The second issue is that `ggplotly` fails to convert the binned colorbar added by `guides(fill=guide_legend(title='Legend'))`.

As a workaround for

1. the first issue you could expand the dataset to include all combinations of `X.Axis`, `Y.Axis` and `Group`.
2. the second issue you could remove the binned colorbar and replace it by a continuous colorscale.

Not perfect but this way the conversion via `ggplotly` gives you the correct plot and a legend. Try this:

```
madeUp=read.table("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/R-graph-gallery/master/DATA/madeUp.csv", sep=",", header=T)

theData <- madeUp %>% 
  group_by(X.Axis, Y.Axis, Group) %>% 
  dplyr::summarize(statistic=mean(randVals, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  ungroup()

# Expand the Dataset to includ all Combinations of X.Axis, Y.Axis and Group
theData1 <- tidyr::expand_grid(X.Axis = 0:49, Y.Axis = 0:30, Group = LETTERS[1:6]) %>% 
  dplyr::left_join(theData)

fig <- ggplot(theData1, aes(X.Axis, Y.Axis)) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0,20), ylim = c(0,20)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,20)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,20))+
  geom_tile(aes(fill=statistic))+
  # Remove the binned colorbar
  # guides(fill=guide_legend(title='Legend'))+
  labs(fill = "Legend") +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill= 'white', color = 'white'),
    panel.grid.major = element_line(color='#E0E0E0'),
    panel.grid.minor = element_line(color='#E0E0E0')
  )+

  ggtitle('Wafer Map')+
  facet_wrap(~Group)+
  # in case of ggplot2: Set the fill color for NA to "transparent"
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = rainbow(100), na.value = "transparent")
fig

ggplotly(fig)
```

[image]

Comment: For anyone interested in the issue about filling gaps, there is a [bug report here](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1957).